# How to get all data-* attributes by Prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tag like this:

```
<a href="#" id="ssd" data-toggle="popover" data-info1="demo text: 1" data-info2="demo text: 2" data-info3="demo text3">Link</a>
```

When I click this link, I have a function like this

```
$('#ssd').click(function (event) {
    var customData;
    // Code to get all the custom data in format like data-info*
});
```

Note, the data-info* like attributes could be any number, that means you could see 1 one of them, named data-info1, or there of them, named data-info1, data-info2, data-info3.

How would I do that, I looked up the JQuery selectors, something like Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"] won't work because the variation here is on name...

If I `console.log($('#ssd').data());` I will get an object with extra attributes that I don't need, `toggle: "popover", bs.popover: Popover`

Any suggestions?

**This is what I did:**

```
dataFullList = $(this).data();
$.each(dataFullList, function (index, value) {
    if (index !== "toggle" && index !== "bs.popover") {
        item.name = value.split(":")[0];
        item.number = value.split(":")[1];
        dataIWant.push(item);
    }
});
```

So I will get a `dataIWant` array without stuff I don't need.

Comment: Just go with `.data()` and deal with having extra. If you're looping over the properties, at most you'll iterate 2-3 extra times. Any alternative solution will result in far more looping.

Comment: As I said, when I loop through the properties, I don't know how to get properties in format like data-info, I go to .data() documention and if you find a solution there, please let me know.

Comment: When you are looping, you will have the key. If the key is "info#" then you know it's one of the ones you want. ***There is no built-in way to filter the properties returned to only the ones you want.***

Comment: Sorry had to edit your question with a better title (easier to find on Goog). Upvoted your Question cause you show a really good effort in formatting it and asking. (The downvotes are probably from before your edit...) Any way, happy coding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Target all elements which `data-*` starts with

#### Custom jQuery selector `selector:dataStartsWith()`

Here's a custom jQuery selector that will help you to:

> Given the ***data-***`foo-bar` prefix , **target** the following elements:
>
> `data-foo-bar`
>   `data-foo-bar-baz`
>
> but **not**:
>
> `data-foo-someting`
>   `data-something`

```js
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], { 
  "dataStartsWith" : function(el, i, p, n) {  
    var pCamel = p[3].replace(/-([a-z])/ig, function(m,$1) { return $1.toUpperCase(); });
    return Object.keys(el.dataset).some(function(i, v){
      return i.indexOf(pCamel) > -1;
    });
  }
});


// Use like:
$('p:dataStartsWith(foo-bar)').css({color:"red"});  

// To get a list of data attributes:
$('p:dataStartsWith(foo-bar)').each(function(i, el){
  console.log( el.dataset );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p data-foo-bar="a">I have data-foo-bar</p>
<p data-foo-bar-baz="b" data-extra="bbb">I have data-foo-bar-baz</p>
<p data-bar="a">I have data-bar DON'T SELECT ME</p>
<p data-something="b">I have data-something DON'T SELECT ME</p>
```

#### Custom jQuery Method `$().dataStartsWith()`

```js
$.fn.dataStartsWith = function(p) {
  var pCamel = p.replace(/-([a-z])/ig, function(m,$1) { return $1.toUpperCase(); });
  return this.filter(function(i, el){
    return Object.keys(el.dataset).some(function(v){
      return v.indexOf(pCamel) > -1;
    });
  });
};


$('p').dataStartsWith("foo-bar").css({color:"red"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p data-foo-bar="a">I have data-foo-bar</p>
<p data-foo-bar-baz="b" data-extra="bbb">I have data-foo-bar-baz</p>
<p data-bar="a">I have data-bar DON'T SELECT ME</p>
<p data-something="b">I have data-something DON'T SELECT ME</p>
```

Comment: @Shabbb the code above is demonstrative and targets only `data-` attributes for a single element. I'll try to expand the answer soon.

Comment: That's what I meant. How can I find all the elements within as well. I just realized it was pulling the attributes from the element itself, but its missing the elements within. Thank you for this great solution, I'll check back frequently for the expanded version.

Comment: Also if the attribute is something like this 'data-mo-fu-six' where it has more than one prefix, it doesn't work.

Comment: Awesome!. The custom method does it for me. Thank you

Comment: @Shabbb just please test in the desired IE browsers since I use `.some()` and `Object.keys` and those only work in newer browsers!

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how I can get the value of each attribute found. Also If multiple matching attributes are found on the same element, '.each()' loops for the number of different elements, not for the number of different attributes found. So if theres 4 matching attributes, and 2 of them are on the  same element, each() loops 2 times.

Answer (score 2):

This function will get the `data-info` attributes and put them into an array:

```
    function getDataInfo($element, i, a) {

        var index = i || 1, array = a || [],
            info = $element.data('info' + index);

        if(info === undefined) {
            return array;
        }

        array['info' + index] = info;

        return getDataInfo($element, index + 1, array);
    }

    $(function() {
        console.log(getDataInfo($('#ssd')));
    });
```

Comment: thank you, I never write function in this way before, open a new gate.

Comment: @XinruiMa You're welcome. Functions like this are known as 'recursive functions', if you wanted to look into it more :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an if condition to isolate the invalid keys while you loop the data. Used as a filter, you can choose to delete the keys you do not want - like this:

```
$('#ssd').click(function(e){
    var data = $(this).data();
    for(var key in data) {
        //here is a condition to use only those data-info items
        if(data.hasOwnProperty(key) && key.indexOf('info') === -1) {
            console.log(key); //just to see which key it is
            delete data[key]; //if you need to build a collection of only data-info keys
        }
    }
});
```

Alternatively, negate the if condition to include only those keys you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Prefix Data](https://github.com/cichy380/prefixData). It is jQuery plugin. Return the value at the prefixed data store for the first element in the set of matched elements. Returned value can be an object based on the attribute values and attributes name structure.

**Usage**

Take any HTML tag with multi `data-*` attributes with the same prefix. In the example we focus on myprefix prefix.

```html
<div id="example-tag"
     data-myprefix='{"property1": "value1", "property2": {"property21": "value21"}, "property3": "value2"}'
     data-myprefix-property2='{"property22": "value22"}'
     data-myprefix-property2-property23="value23"
     data-myprefix-property3="overwite-value3"
     data-myprefix-property4='{"property41": "value41"}'
     data-other="We do not read it"></div>
```

If you want to read data from data-myprefix and every `data-myprefix-*` attribute you can use `.prefixData()` with given prefix.

```js
$('#example-tag').prefixData('myprefix');
```

The previous example returns the object:

```sh
{
    property1: "value1",
    property2: {
        property21: "value21",
        property22: "value22",
        property23: "value23"
    },
    property3: "overwite-value3",
    property4: {
        property41: "value41"
    }
}
```