# Saving specific naming convention data-attributes into an object

Tags: jquery

I have div tag something like below

```
<div class="class" data-mark-comp="comp1" data-conf-property1="p1" data-conf-property2="p2" data-conf-property3="p3"</div>
```

I want to create an object which consists of `data-conf-*` attributes

```
var conf = $(".class").data() <br>
```

I tried the above, but it consists of all the attributes which I don't need as per my requirement.

```
var conf = $(".class").data("conf-*") - this one also not working
```

Comment: Can't understand your question. Please be more clear.

Comment: updated it. I want to create an object and it should contain only data-conf-* attributes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973380/how-to-get-all-data-attributes-by-prefix

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create your own plugin.

This one accepts regex to compare against the property:-

```js
$.fn.ddata = function(regex) {
  var objs = [];
  this.each(function() {
    var obj = {};
    for (var prop in this.dataset)
      if (regex.test(prop))
        obj[prop] = this.dataset[prop];
    objs.push(obj);
  });
  return objs;
};

var conf = $('.class').ddata(/^conf/);

console.log(conf);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="class" data-mark-comp="comp1" data-conf-property1="p1" data-conf-property2="p2" data-conf-property3="p3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all elements that are part of the `.class` div and create an array of attributes for the relevant entries using:

```
  var conf= [];
  $(".class").each(function() {
    $.each(this.attributes, function() {
      if (this.name.substring(0, 5)=='data-') {          
        conf[this.name.substring(5)]= this.value;
      }
    });
  });
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/wpjpb7m0/) of the above with comments.

**Or simply** use BenG's nice version of a property selector with variable attribute names.

Answer (score 0):

If you can alter the source code, I would just put all of it into a single `data` attribute:

```
<div class="class" data-conf="{ property1: 'p1', property2: 'p2' }">
```

[Because](https://api.jquery.com/data/) excerpt:

> When the data attribute is an object (starts with '{') or array (starts with '[') then jQuery.parseJSON is used to parse the string; it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names. If the value isn't parseable as a JavaScript value, it is left as a string.

Thus it becomes insanely easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
var data = $(".class").data();
var conf = {};
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  if(key.startsWith("conf")) conf[key]=value;
});
console.log(conf); // just for verification -- comment this line afterwards
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class" data-mark-comp="comp1" data-conf-property1="p1" data-conf-property2="p2" data-conf-property3="p3">
</div>
```